Why is my this question being kept closed for long?
Is there any specific reason, why this question has been kept closed?
Smallest square with pentominoes
I would like to educate myself regarding the fact that, since it has been already two days and even more, why is not any moderator of the network showing any activity regarding the question. The question says to be focused and I have edited the question to make it focused, but still, it did not receive any attention.
What else can I do? Except waiting....

Five people need to vote to reopen. I did so very soon after you edited, and three others followed. Thus, only one more vote is needed. Unfortunately it seems people do not check the reopen queue. I will advertise the question in chat.

Thanks, it really helped. I did not know that fact. @bobble
